Missing overview ruler or I cannot see it
In eclipse and dbeaver there is option to show annotations on vertical ruler and overview ruler. But I cannot for the life of me find the overview ruler? I can see vertical ruler but overview is missing or disabled with no preference options to turn it on.
Google search shows the attached image but how do I activate or see it. Overview and vertical rulers in Eclipse
Under annotations I enabled options to show annotations on vertical ruler and also overview ruler. Vertical ruler works fine but overview is nowhere to be seen.
The key feature of the overview ruler is that the length of the ruler you see represents the complete file being edited, This provides a convenient way to jump to annotated parts of the file without excessive scrolling How these various annotations appear is defined by your Workbench > Editors > Annotations preferences

The Vertical ruler is on the left, the Overview ruler is on the right--and blank until there are annotations to show.

I added annotations on two different computers  and still nothing showed on left or right. I even tried latest version of dbeaver standalone and as plug-in on latest version of eclipse.

What do you mean by "added annotations"? That's a programmatic term for Eclipse text internals and not something users usually do directly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry I meant enabled the annotations options in preference.
